# Refrigerant flow

Tags: hvac, refrigeration

I am an HVAC engineer.
I know that in the refrigeration cycle the expansion valve controls the refrigerant flow rate but if flow through a positive displacement compressor is fixed, how does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that the mass flow rate is the same between both but the volume flow rate will change because of the valve. The pump has a fixed mass flow rate at a given condition but the valve changes the condition. If the valve is of the thermostatic type then this follows.
"The purpose of the thermostatic valve is to control the rate at which the refrigerant passes from the liquid line into the evaporator and to keep the pressure difference between the high and low pressure sides of the refrigeration system."[reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/expansion-valve#:%7E:text=An%20expansion%20valve%20is%20basically,orifice%20is%20now%20a%20low)